# Angular Cards Cut Off in Tabs

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I ran into the problem, that the cards within a tab navigation in Angular Material were cut off.

---

[image]

Comment: It's probably because the elements above it are forcing the `md-tabs` to occupy a limited height.

Comment: No, this is not it. The parent of `<md-tabs>` tag is the `<main>` tag which has no height specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `md-tabs` element on that site (URL is no longer available) does not have the attribute `md-dynamic-height`:

[image]

Taking the markup in your question I created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/dpZzyw?editors=1010#0). If you remove that attribute you will see the problem you mention.

From the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTabs):

[image]

Comment: You are so right. I should have seen this myself, thank you for opening my eyes.